# How does one go about de-composing a regular expression?

Tags: regex

Is there a concept of scope in regular expressions?

In this

```
^(\(\d{3}\)|^\d{3}[.-]?)?\d{3}[.-]?\d{4}$
```

for matching a 10 digit North American telephone number, with or withour parenthesis, hyphens or dots (another one of my attempts while understanding reg. expressions)

I'm having trouble understanding, when you go about decomposing an expression like this, how do you go about it? How do you tell what is scoped from this to that?

Okey, it starts with a `^` and ends with a `$`, both ends of lines.
Just before the end there is a three digit number followed by an optional dot or hyphen, and a four digit number. That part is clear.

So that leaves us with

```
 (\(\d{3}\)|^\d{3}[.-]?)?
```

**What is the purpose here of the caret, if we already had one at the beginning?**

**And what does this tells us apart that the first three digit number can be in parenthesis or without them followed by a dot or a hyphen?**

I'm trying to figure out a sort of systematic way, when I find an unknown expression somewhere, how to go about to de compose it and see what it does?

---

***Edit: From what others suggested in the comments, the second caret seems to be unnecessary. Testing it in [RegexPal](http://www.regexpal.com/) confirmed that on the following***

```
^(\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}[.-]?)?\d{3}[.-]?\d{4}$

^(123)456.7890
^123.456.7890
^456.7890
```

***but not***

```
^   (123)456.7890
^   123.456.7890
```

***(caret designating the beginning of the line). Can anyone think of an example where the second caret would be needed?***

Comment: That last sentence sounds moronic, but I'm sure you understand what I meant.

Comment: I'd say the caret inside the expression is unnecessary, but I'd be interested what others say about that. *"And what does this tells us apart..."* Not much else. The whole "subexpression" is optional. What more do you expect?

Comment: You might want to check this out: http://www.regexper.com/#%5E(%5C(%5Cd%7B3%7D%5C)%7C%5E%5Cd%7B3%7D%5B.-%5D%3F)%3F%5Cd%7B3%7D%5B.-%5D%3F%5Cd%7B4%7D%24
That site really comes in handy explaining regex

Comment: @FelixKling - Just wanted to hear what, as you said, the others had to say about it. And to hear whether I maybe mixed up the scoping, so that caret came as another case of the one at the beginning of the expression.

Comment: @rinukkusu - Wow. That site is really beautiful. I'll be trying it out in the future, for sure.

Comment: spend the $50 and buy [regexbuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/). absolutely indispensable.

Answer (score 0):

answering this question now as it looks like you had some unresolved questions.

> Is there a concept of scope in regular expressions?
>
> Can anyone think of an example where the second caret would be needed?

Yes, kind of, and yes. Let's start with the second.

**Multiple Carets**

You can have multiple carets, and that can be quite helpful.

Here is a simple example ([demo here](http://regex101.com/r/tN1fY9)):

```
(?<=^|\b)dog|^cat
```

This regex either matches: 
 1. `dog`, if the lookahead `(?<=^|\b)` can successfully assert that it is either at the beginning of a line, or preceded by a word boundary (therefore, `dog` in `hotdog` will not match), or...
 2. `cat`, if it is at the beginning of a line.

In this particular example, you could rearrange the grouping to rewrite this as `^(?:dog|cat)|\bdog`, but that is not the point. They point is that multiple carets are possible and potentially useful: at several points in the regex, you may want to assert that the engine is currently positioned at the beginning of the string (which the `^` anchor does).

**Scope**

You are wanting to ask about the "scope" of the caret. The scope of any token `t` is the exact position `p` in the string where the engine is currently positioned. The engine can only match the token there. If it fails to match `t` at that position, and there is no backtracking possible, then the match fails. Next, the engine attempts a whole new match starting one position in the string further from the one where it started the match attempt. (Usually that is unrelated to `p`, unless `t` was the pattern's first token.) During that match attempt, if the engine manages to match all the tokens before `t`, then once again the scope of `t` will be the position of the engine in the string at that time. That position may or may not be the same as the earlier `p`.

Hope this helps, let me know if any questions remain. :)